# How do you allow certain views in Django Rest Framework to be accessed with an unauthenticated request?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I'm working on a basic Django Rest Framework API app and i'm trying to implement a Token based authentication system. I want to block off every view thats requested via an unauthenticated request except for the login and signup views. Currently when I try to login or sign up the request is denied and I get "Authentication credentials were not provided.".

How can I setup my views so that login and signup don't need a token?

I've looked at permissions and authentication classes but don't really know where I need to go from there.

Comment: Are you using a third party app for  Token authentication or a custom token authentication class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the default permission policy globally as described in the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy) and then override the `permission_classes` only for the sign up and login like so:

```
...
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny    

class SignUpView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
...
```

Comment: wow thanks it works! Feel like an idiot for not looking further down the page lol :P